# mongodb on node js race conditions

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using nodeJs with mongodb driver to store some data.

I want to persist this data in my js script.

so... I wrote this small code:

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {

    assert.equal(null, err);

    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{

        console.log("Yes");

    }
    var cursor =db.collection('mydb').updateOne( { "name":"id"},
        {$inc: { count: 1 } });
    var x;
    var cursor=db.collection('mydb').find( { "name":"id"} ) ;
    cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        if (doc != null) {
            x=doc.count;
            console.log(x); //right value
        }  
    }); 
    console.log(x); //undefined
```

however, there is asynchronism going on here and I don't use a callback so what happens is that until the database finishs its business the x that is prtined to the console log is undefined.

so my output is this:

```
Yes
undefined
Connected correctly to server.
140
```

how can I add a callback to solve it (or solve it in any other way..)?

Comment: Could you specify what u want to achieve?

Comment: 1. get a value from the database,  2. save this object I got to x (<==> outside varible) in my global scope and 3. print this varible after this value was inserted from the global scope...

Comment: its async so the x is same only, but by the time it (the last line is run) the cursor.each callback isnt called. it'll happen only at a later future tick of the clock

Comment: exactly .. any idea on how to solve this async problem?

Comment: your upper console.log is the right way to do it. if you want you could put a function below and call it inside the cursor.each